# No such file or directory -- rake [PROJECT-FOLDER-NAME] init ... (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have rails 3.2.0 application and ruby is - 2.1.2.
When I'm running below command

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I'm getting error like

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- rake [PROJECT-FOLDER-NAME] init ... (LoadError)
rake aborted!
```

What's wrong with Precompile not getting so please Help me

Comment: try with - run bundle install

Comment: @vishwasnahar Still not working. getting same error.